# Outlook 2013 marking email read

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I’m using MS Outlook 2013 and have four email accounts with IMAP settings. One of my account’s email becomes read without reading them on any device in few seconds, reading pane and all other setting are identical on all accounts.
How can I set Outlook so that it will not mark these emails as read without reading them?

Comment: What you describe is set in the Tools/Options/Other/Reading Pane.  If it is behaving differently from those settings, it will take some Sherlock Holmes.

Comment: I edited my answer, I think the problem might be a rule on that specific email account.

Comment: What rules are running on the folder?

Comment: Thanks for the help. There is no rule selected or created in "Rules and Alerts"

Comment: When you say "four different e-mails", it is important to note how you connect to those e-mail accounts. Are they all Exchange Online, POP3, IMAP, etc? Also, are these e-mail accounts being shared/read with another client. For example, if you use IMAP or Exchange, you could potentially have another e-mail client reading the e-mail.

Comment: Can you edit your post? Your first sentence is confusing and hard to understand.

Comment: using IMAP setting on all mails

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2013, you have to go to File > Options > Mail
Then, under the section that says "Outlook Panes" click the button that says "Reading Pane"
There you can change the settings to not mark email as read when seen on the reading pane.

The settings should apply to all email accounts.

If you have already checked these settings and still have problems, then it's likely that you have a specific rule for that email account that marks email as read.
To see what are your current rules for each account go to
File > Info > Rules and Alert
Then select the email account you are having issues with and check if there is any rule that could be causing mail to be marked as read.

Comment: That's another route to get to the same panel.  @Tanveer indicated that those settings were identical for all accounts but only one was not working per the setting.